# Running a bash script after startup in an NGINX docker container

Tags: bash, docker, nginx

I need send curl request to itself  while docker container starting.
But after nginx starting any command not working because nginx stay in foreground.

Example of entrypoint.sh

```
echo "Starting memcached"
memcached memcache -m 1024 -d
service memcached restart
echo "Starting php-fpm"
php-fpm -D

echo "Starting Nginx"
nginx -g 'daemon off;'

!!this part not working!!!

check_robots=$(wp wpc check_robots) 
echo "Starting check robots"

if [ "$check_robots" != "Robots checked successfully!" ]; then
    echo ERROR:  Robots checked failed
    exit 0
fi

exec "$@"
```

Comment: how about not forcing `nginx` to run in the foreground? (note that you might need to give the webserver time to properly startup before checking whether it serves some files or not)

Comment: I think I would run the check in a separate container

Comment: ...and also memcached and nginx should be in separate containers.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it would work, but lanching nginx to background directly could be a solution, like so:

```
nginx -g 'daemon off;' &
```

Have not tested in case of Docker entrypoint though.